# Efficiently determining maximum allowed euclidean distance between lists of colors

Tags: algorithm, ruby, time-limit-exceeded, clustering

I was recently tasked with determining which hex RGB colors in list  *color_list* are nearest to each hex RGB color in list *target_colors*, using euclidean distance as the measuring stick, and only returning items that are within 10 distance from each target color.  My first pass at this was for each item in *target_colors*, check the distance between it and everything in *color_list*, and return the colors at or below the target distance. This works well enough when *color_list* is small. But when *color_list* is large, looping over the entire list for each item in *target_colors* is slow. I am wondering if there is a better way to go about doing this, so that I don't have to loop over the entire list every time.

My first thought was to cache the results, but given that there are 16 million potential colors, that is potentially 2*16m^2 combinations, it would not be very space efficient.

My next thought was that perhaps the source color list can be sorted in a way that would make searching it faster, but I have to loop over all of the colors to get the distance as the thing to sort on, and I would not be in any better of shape.

My last thought was that given an r, g, or b color, perhaps I could eliminate colors that are obviously going to be out of range. If I have a color like #AABBAA, I instinctively know that #001100 is going to be way too far away, so I could sort the source list of colors l, then eliminate anything that smells like its out of range. But, I get back to the "well I would calculate the distance to figure out if it smells out of range", and I'm back to square one.

distance.rb:

```
TARGET_DISTANCE = 10.0

# calculate the euclidiean distance between two hex colors
def color_distance(c1, c2)
  c1_parts = c1.split('').each_slice(2).map{|c| c.join}.to_a
  c2_parts = c2.split('').each_slice(2).map{|c| c.join}.to_a
  r_diff = c1_parts[0].to_i(16) - c2_parts[0].to_i(16)
  g_diff = c1_parts[1].to_i(16) - c2_parts[1].to_i(16)
  b_diff = c1_parts[2].to_i(16) - c2_parts[2].to_i(16)
  Math.sqrt(r_diff**2 + g_diff**2 + b_diff**2)
end

def random_color
  3.times.map{rand(254).to_s(16).rjust(2, '0')}.join()
end

color_list = []
1.upto(10000) { color_list << random_color }

target_colors  = []
1.upto(100) { target_colors << random_color }

results = {}
target_colors.each do |t|
  results[t] ||= []
  color_list.each do |c|
   distance = color_distance(c, t)
   if distance <= TARGET_DISTANCE
     results[t] << [c, distance]
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) perhaps?

Comment: Is there some reason why `random_color` uses `rand(254)` rather than `rand(256)`?

Comment: I was debugging something and left it in, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @vnp says, a solution involving an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) would a more efficient way to find neighboring points.

Before you implement one, though, there are some huge time savings you can get by making some trivial changes:

- Computing square roots is computationally intensive.  Do it only when you need to.
- Parsing hex values into integers is somewhat slow, especially when you do it using a lot of string and array operations.  It would be more efficient to parse the entire 6-hex-digit string into an integer, then use bit manipulation.
- The same goes for generating random colors.  I don't know why you used `rand(254)` rather than `rand(256)`.  If you allow color components `FE` and `FF`, then it becomes a simple matter of generating a 24-bit random number, and formatting it as hex.  (Better yet, avoid converting the colors into their hex representation altogether, and just store them as integers.)

In addition, `1.upto(10000) { color_list << random_color }` is poor Ruby style.  Write it using `.map` instead (like you did in the implementation of `random_colors`).

I don't know why you wrote `results[t] ||= []` instead of `results[t] = []`.

With just those changes, I'm able to reduce the execution time by 90% already.

```
def color_dist_sq(c1, c2)
  c1 = c1.to_i(16)
  c2 = c2.to_i(16)
  [0, 8, 16].map do |bits|
    ((c1 >> bits & 0xff) - (c2 >> bits & 0xff)) ** 2
  end.inject(:+)
end

def random_color
  '%06x' % rand(1 << 24)
end

TARGET_DISTANCE_SQ = 10**2
color_list = 10000.times.map { random_color }
target_colors = 100.times.map { random_color }

results = {}
target_colors.each do |t|
  results[t] = color_list.inject([]) do |result, c|
    dist_sq = color_dist_sq(c, t)
    result << [c, Math.sqrt(dist_sq)] if dist_sq <= TARGET_DISTANCE_SQ
    result
  end
end
```